# Sending ASCII characters on Mac USB/RS232 cable

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, usb, rs232

I have a RS232C/USB cable to connect an electronic device to my iMac Intel (MacOSX SnowLeo 10.6.3).

Is there a utility program that allows for sending ASCII characters on the USB port that the RS232C device will understand?

If possible, I'd rather avoid programming. I'd prefer an Automator script or a simple program with a GUI.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Normally your cable should have a Prolific PL-2303 component to implement USB to serial port. Drivers can be [downloaded here](http://www.prolific.com.tw/eng/downloads.asp?ID=31). Once installed you can use a terminal emulator to send characters to your device. You have these choices (untested for me as I don't have the hardware with me):

- use [ZTerm](http://homepage.mac.com/dalverson/zterm/) (It is very old and shareware)
- use Terminal.app and see [this article](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20061109133825654)
- use [QuickTerm](http://www.gelhaus.net/cgi-bin/showpage.py?cocoa/+quickterm.html) (might be the best solution, but again untested)

Comment: I'm still waiting for my USB/RS cable (from HK). I'll give a try to QuickTerm as soon as I get it.

Will let you know

Answer (score 1):

You will not interact with the USB device. The USB device should provide drivers that will create a virtual serial device in `/dev/` when you plug in your device. Once the device is plugged in and the driver has created the virtual serial device, communication takes place over the callout device file `/dev/xxx.cu` or the TTY device file `/dev/xxx.tty` (where `xxx` is particular to your driver). Communication might be as simple as `cat`ting a text file with `stdout` redirected to that path. Failing that, a serial-aware interface such as those mentioned by CharlesB might be necessary. If you are looking for a command line tool, try [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/), which has flags to configure the baudrate, parity, and bitwidth of messages sent across a serial port.