# Simplest way to send characters to USB serial device on Mac using script

Tags: mac, terminal, serial, com

I have a simple serial device that I need to talk to (but not listen to) periodically via command.

The device is connected OK as `/dev/usbxxx`.

What is the simplest/easiest way to do this?

Installing software (python, minicom, whatever) is fine.

The exact scenario is I have an arduino device (a [Cube4](http://www.freetronics.com.au/products/cube4-4x4x4-rgb-led-cube#.VK8IDDtdbCQ)) that I want to use as a build light. Periodically, I will poll the CI server or use RSS etc and need to tell it what color to display. Using session-based solutions (like screen) seems like they won't work because the terminal command runs elsewhere (although I suppose I could remote to the screen session, send the chars via who knows what, then disconnect).

Comment: A related question was asked on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/144751/sending-ascii-characters-on-mac-usb-rs232-cable?rq=1) that lists some good tools.

Answer (score 0):

echo "characters" > /dev/usbxxx

Simplest I can think of, and should work in zsh

Comment: Don't you have to set the baud rate, stop bits, and parity bits?

Comment: @LawrenceC Depends on the device.  I certainly didn't have to when I was doing something similar to OP.  But if you're trying to use *real* RS-232 then yeah, you have to account for everything the standard expects.

Comment: `echo "0xAA 0xBB 0x03 0x01 0x01 0xEE" > /dev/tty.usbserial-FT8YXN7Z 9600` isn't working for me. The terminal just freezes